# iPhone: Scan Cellular Network

Tags: iphone, network, sim

When I scan for Cellular Network on my iPhone (Settings app → General → Cellular → Network Selection → Manual), the only networks that I get is from my ISP, the company that I bough my SIM card from.

Is there a way to get all the other cellular networks? Why is my iPhone not looking at all the networks, and only at the one that my SIM is supposed to recognize?

Comment: I believe the SIM determines which networks to recognize.  Therefore, it makes sense that the only network your SIM is authorized to recognize is the only one it shows you.  Why do you think you should see other networks?

Comment: Yes that was my first intuition too. I would have like to see other networks just for experiment. See which network are available at my location. It could be useful if only one carrier is available and quickly know which one is it.

Comment: How long are you waiting for available networks to appear?  Some sites I've read say it could take up to 2-4 min for available networks to appear.

Comment: Yeah I have waited quite a while. After waiting, only my carrier's networks appeared.

Comment: This question might get closed as off-topic (because it appears to not be related to the iPhone).  You can also contact your carrier and ask if you should be able to see other networks using their SIM.  They'll tell you.